# mac error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, macos, openssl, certificate

I'm writing a python program to communicate with Qlik sense server via Websocket. Connection happens through certificates. When I try to connect I get a error message saying "unable to get local issuer certificate". I tried to narrow down the problem and I get the same error message when I try to verify certificates with openssl.

OS: Mac

Note: I already installed the root.pem certificate to system and made it trusted. Still it threw same error message.

```
OpenSSL> verify -CAfile root.pem client.pem
client.pem: OK
OpenSSL> 
OpenSSL> verify client.pem
client.pem: CN = QlikClient
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
error in verify
OpenSSL>
```

In case anyone to look at

```
senseHost = “SERVER”
privateKeyPath = "/Users/abc/”


## userDirectory and userId can be found at QMC -> Users
userDirectory, userId = “DIR”, “user”

url = "wss://" + senseHost + “:999/app"  # valid
certs = ({"ca_certs": privateKeyPath + "root.pem",
          "certfile": privateKeyPath + "client.pem",
          "keyfile": privateKeyPath + "client_key.pem",
          "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
          "server_side": False
          })
ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True
ws = create_connection(url, sslopt=certs,
                       header={'X-Qlik-User: UserDirectory=%s; UserId=%s' % (userDirectory, userId)})
```

Comment: Does `root.pem` directly sign `client.pem ` or is there an intermediate certificate?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?  I get the same error: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)